# How to copy an existing DB in SQL Server 2008 r2 management studio?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to copy an existing DB, which exists in SQL Server 2008 r2 management studio including data.

Is there any option to copy database in the management studio?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right click on the database in Object Explorer -> Tasks -> Copy Database

Comment: just noticed it does not always show up: prob to do with sql server version

Comment: Using Copy Database has its limitations too -> https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188664(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You also need to make sure the SQL Agent (SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER)) service is running

Answer (score 0):

**Right** Click Database which you want to export. Then choose task from the options now you can **export** the data or you can **generate script** which you can run on another server.

For Generating the script choose it and wizard will open up. then decide where you want to save the script.

You have  to remind you have to hit **advanced button** and select type of data to choose select **schema and data** for getting data in the database other it will select only structure of the database.